# Script to import multiple priv keys in Electrum

Tags: electrum, script, private-key-import, import, electrum-console

DuckDuckGo turns up nothing of interest. How to import multiple priv keys in Electrum from a file using Electrum console or shell script, for all derivable valid BTC addresses? (1,3,bc1)

Eventually I would like to pipe the output of one script directly into an import script.

The file is in format:

```
BTC Pattern: <pattern>  
BTC Address: <bitcoin address beginning with one>  
BTC Privkey: <bitcoin address beginning with five>
...
```

Comment: Does [this](http://docs.electrum.org/en/latest/faq.html#can-i-import-private-keys-from-other-bitcoin-clients) help?

Comment: @KappaDev Thank you, I can filter my input file and paste a bunch. Updated question for derivable addresses.

Answer (score 0):

First of all get rid of all that junk. One priv key per line is all you need. So use `grep privkey filename|cut -d":" -f2 > clean-file.txt`. Then call this  python script with that file as an argument:

```
import sys
from electrum import bitcoin
f = open(sys.argv[1], "r")
for privkey in f:
    privkey=privkey.strip()
    orig_format,secret,compressed=bitcoin.deserialize_privkey( privkey)
    formats = [ bitcoin.serialize_privkey( secret, False, "p2pkh"), bitcoin.serialize_privkey( secret, True, "p2pkh"), bitcoin.serialize_privkey( secret, True, "p2wpkh"), bitcoin.serialize_privkey( secret, True, "p2wpkh-p2sh") ]
    for thing in formats:
        print(thing)
```

It'll output all the private keys in the various formats.